# xcodebuild cause fatal error but in Xcode, compilation is OK

Tags: xcode, configuration, compilation, xcodebuild

I have a weird thing when I try to compile with xcodebuild.
If I open the project on the mac with XCode, the code compile without any warning.

If I use the following command line :
xcodebuild -configuration Debug -target myApp PROVISIONING_PROFILE=B5AD0E27-B224-4962-B0DC-XXXXXXXX

I have some compilation error :
    /Users/myUser/.jenkins/jobs/myApp/workspace/prj/Controllers/DeclarerEtape1Adresse.m:75:6: error: receiver type 'DeclarerEtape1Adresse' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'rechercheAdresse' [4]
         [self rechercheAdresse];
          ^
    1 error generated.

This errors can appear in external code (taken from github). It seems that the compilator is much strict in command line mode than with Xcode.

Is there any specific configuration in command line ?

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: The underlying compiler should be the same, regardless of using the IDE or xcodebuild. However, it's possible you are using a different tool-chain: 'which xcodebuild' or xcodeselect might help check if the Xcode.app you're using corresponds to the toolchain used by xcodebuild.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The command 'which xcodebuild' returns /usr/bin/xcodebuild in both environment

Comment: check your `export` for me `unset CPATH` worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James, you're the boss :p I tried `xcodebuild -version` on both environment and the ci server used an old SDK 4.2.X. So I used the `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` and it fixes the issue